# How to set user environment variables in Windows Server 2008 R2 as a normal user?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, environment-variables

In older versions of Windows, it was just open the Control Panel, select the System applet, select the Advanced tab, and then hit the Environment variables button.  As a normal user, you could edit the "User variables" but not the "System variables".

In Windows Server 2008 R2, if I try to hit the Advanced System settings option in the System applet, it prompts for the Administrator password.

Comment: good thread but I voted for it to be moved to server fault

Answer (score 90):

You can also use this direct command line to open the Advanced System Properties:

```
sysdm.cpl
```

Then go to the Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables

Comment: This is the way to do it.  Boy, on Windows Server 2012, this has become ridiculously complicated.  See technet for how to add an environment variable in Windows Server 2012.  They tell you to install the Group Policy Management Console.  Which is unnecessary.  @AlexCode's solution is the correct one to get the old familiar dialog.

Comment: Handy command, but this still requires elevated privileges and thus will not work for a normal user.  OP's own answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 67):

OK I found it.  Arg, an exercise in frustration.  They left the old window menu traversal path for changing environment variables in there, but limited access to administrators only.  As a normal user, if you want to change it, you need to go through a different set of options to arrive at the same frigging window.

**Control Panel** -> **User Accounts** -> **User Accounts** -> **Change my environment variables.**

Answer (score 21):

Step by step instructions:

- Go to Control Panel \System and Security\System
- Click on Change Settings
- Go to “Advance” tab
- Click on Environment Variables

Comment: I don't think that works for the poster's question... see the bit about not wanting to do this as administrator

Comment: On my WinSvr 2008 R2 box replace the 2nd & 3rd bullets with: Click on "Advanced system settings"

Answer (score 6):

Under "Start" enter "environment" in the search field. That will list the option to change the system variables directly in the start menu.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done from the command line using the `SETX` command. For example to 'move' your temporary files to another disk:

```
SETX TEMP d:\tmp
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this command. I am now able to set env var to non interactive users. +1. It's really helpfull for service accounts that need to run batches.

Answer (score 2):

In command line prompt:

```
set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER
SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe
```

Now you can set user environment variables.

Comment: Well you can set visual effects/performance settings the same way. :)

Answer (score 2):

I created a godmode folder on the desktop.  just create a new folder on the desktop and call it GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
it will name the folder as godmode and populate the content with various config options, you can then just type in ENVIRO in the search to find the relevant config option, open it and it opens sysdm.cpl in the advanced tab, you can change the environment variables from there.

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways

1) This runs the GUI editor for the user environment variables.  It does exactly what the OP wanted to do and does not prompt for administrative credentials.

```
rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

(bonus: This works on Windows Vista to Windows 10 for desktops and Windows Server 2008 through Server 2016.  It does not work on Windows NT, 2000, XP, and 2003. However, on the older systems you can use sysdm.cpl without the ",EditEnvironmentVariables" parameter and then navigate to the Advanced tab and then Environment Variables button.)

2) Use the SETX command from the command prompt. This is like the set command but updates the environment that's stored in the registry.  Unfortunately, SETX is not as easy to use as the built in SET command. There's no way to list the variables for example.  Thus it's impossible to do something such as appending a folder to the user's PATH variable.  While SET will display the variables you don't know which ones are user vs. system variables and the PATH that's shown is a combination of both.

3) Use regedit and navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment

Keep in mind that changes to the user's environment does not immediately propagate to all processes currently running for that user.  You can see this in a command prompt where your changes will not be visible if you use SET.  For example

```
rem Add a user environment variable named stackoverflow that's set to "test"
setx stackoverflow test
set st
```

This should show all variables whose names start with the letters "st".  If there are none then it displays "`Environment variable st not defined`".
Exit the command prompt and start another.  Try `set st` again
and you'll see

```
stackoverflow=test
```

To delete the stackoverflow variable use

```
setx stackoverflow ""
```

It will respond with "`SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.`" which looks strange given you want to delete the variable.  However, if you start a new command prompt then `set st` will show that there are no variables starting with the letters "st"

(correction - I discovered that `setx stackoverflow ""` did not delete the variable.  It's in the registry as an empty string.  The `SET` command though interprets it as though there is no variable. `if not defined stackoverflow echo Not defined` says it's not defined.)

Comment: Also discussed [here](/q/9546324).