# Error when generating an SSH key with Git: "no such file"

Tags: git

I continually run into the same error when I try to generate an SSH key:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/konrad/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

Here I press enter.

```
Could not create directory '/home/konrad/.ssh'
```

Then I enter my passphrases.

```
open /home/konrad/.ssh/id_rsa failed: No such file or directory.
Saving the key failed: /home/konrad/.ssh/id_rsa.
```

I've tried re-installing Git multiple times, but that hasn't helped. I think it may be because C:/Users/Konrad should be the default directory, rather than /home. Any advice?

Comment: Are you on windows? Are you using cygwin, or some gui installer? Try using a directory that exists for storing your keypair when it asks (so type in C:\Users\Konrad instead of accepting the default by pressing enter).

Comment: Well I had to accept default, guess it was because I only typed Users and not C/Users

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On msysgit, you need first to set the user environment variable `HOME` (which isn't set by default in Windows).

`HOME` can be set to any directory you want, you only have to make sure you have the right to write in it (and that the directory exists and a `.ssh` under it exists too).

Comment: strangely enough, I never had to set that env var on my setup.  Either the msysgit installer did it for me waaaay back when, or it was already set - could this have been removed from the msysgit installer since git...ohh, maybe git 1.6.6-ish?

Comment: @Obsidian_: I somehow doubt that any installer would set that kind of variable for you: too much potential side-effect. On Windows, you really need to set it up yourself.

Comment: How do you set the HOME variable? Mine seems to be set to "/h", which might be problem why I get the same error as OP.

Comment: @user1809923 http://superuser.com/q/25037/141 http://stackoverflow.com/a/1493058/6309

Answer (score 4):

Drop to a command line and type:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

And follow the prompts there. I'm pretty sure `git`'s doing exactly that under the hood for you.